# Bundler on Heroku won't run correct version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, gem-bundler

I am working in aws c9 and I am trying to send my app to heroku but it keeps telling me I am running the wrong version of bundler, so I run `gem install bundler` locally and I get 2.0.1, but on Heroku it keeps running 1.17.1 and I can't change this version.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't think there is anything we can do to help you with this. That error appears pretty fatal to me.

Comment: Well there has to be some way to fix as I have restarted my app from the beginning several times now attempting to make it work....

Answer (score 1):

Heroku pin the bundler version for reasons of their own:

> The Bundler version on Heroku is carefully curated. A balance needs to be struck between supporting new Bundler features and stability. The work we put into curating the Bundler version ensures maximum stability, and avoids deprecation and notification cycles on Bundler as it changes, or as bugs are fixed or security issues are patched by Heroku.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-version

They're still on 1.17.1 at time of writing, but that shouldn't generally be a problem.

EDIT

This might be a problem because your local version of bundler is later than that. This is especially the case if you're running bundler 2+ locally, because that creates a `Gemfile.lock` which won't allow older versions to install from it.

If that's the case then you need to downgrade your local version and rebundle:

```
local> gem uninstall bundler
local> gem install bundler -v 1.17.1 (or whatever version)
local> rm Gemfile.lock
local> bundle install
```

Comment: this is what I get:

Comment: remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile.
remote:  !

Comment: and then Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.

Comment: @DonaldLundgren OK, if that's the case then you'll need to downgrade your local version of bundler. It puts the version into the `Gemfile.lock`, and apparently bundler 2+ creates lockfiles that can't run with old versions. Locally, do something like: `gem uninstall bundler ; gem install bundler -v 1.17.1 ; bundle update`. If `bundle update` fails then just delete your Gemfile.lock and type `bundle install` again.

Comment: ok that worked but now it wont precompile assets..Precompiling assets failed.

Comment: I actually got it, my fallback was wrong. Ty very much

Comment: @DonaldLundgren if this worked, please accept the answer.